# How do you order a oneToMany join table in hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate, criteria

Say I have a class Mother with a oneToMany mapping to Kittens

```
@Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate = true)
@Table(name = "Mother")

.....

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=Kittens.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="motherId")
private List<Kittens> kittens;
```

I am using the criteria Api to provide a list

```
Criteria criteria = this.getSession().createCriteria(Mother.class);
Criterion MotherType = Restrictions.eq("type", "domesticated");
criteria.add(MotherType)
.addOrder(Order.asc("motherName"))
.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
.setFetchMode("kittens", FetchMode.JOIN)
// .addOrder(Order.asc("kittens.kittenName"));
List test = criteria.list();
```

Works fine until I try to add the order of the kittens field kittenName

I've also tried adding the @OrderBy(value="kittenName") annotation under the Kitten @OneToMany(...etc ) which works fine until you use the criteria API and this order will precede any other order statements in the sql.

Cheers in advance for any help...

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You need to add the [`@javax.persistence.OrderBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderBy.html) annotation to your `kittens` list.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
           targetEntity=Kittens.class,
           cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="motherId")
@OrderBy("kittenName")
private List<Kittens> kittens;
```

@See

- Hibernate Annotations Reference Guide
- [Chapter 2.2.5. Mapping entity associations/relationships](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association)
- Subchapter 2.2.5.3.4. Indexed collections (List, Map)

Comment: Hi Ralph. I've tried that but the generated sql puts the kittenName order before the MotherName order. ie select ... order by kittens.kittenName asc, mother.motherName asc. And I'm trying to achive order by mother.motherName asc, kittens.kittenName asc. Thanks

Comment: @user456147: It seems that I do not really understand what you want to do? Load what, in which order? And what does not work like you want?

Comment: apologies if I didn't make it clear. I want to order by MotherName then KittenName. The order is the other way round if I put the OrderBy on the Kitten entity.

Comment: @user456147: "I want to order by MotherName then KittenName."? - Do you mean, "I want to order the Kittens by Mother Name"?

Comment: Hi Ralph ended up using criteria.createAlias("genres", "genreAlias", CriteriaSpecification.INNER_JOIN) instead of setFetchMode(... SELECT) yhis allowed me to set the order as you suggested in your answer with @OrderBy. Cheers.

Comment: And be sure that you are using a List and not a Set.

Comment: @androniennn: if you use a Set (SortedSet) then the sorting must be done in the application, but it is not possible to sort them in the database